# Dynamic keyword in Java

Tags: java, dynamic

Is there a dynamic keyword in Java or a keyword which is similar to the dynamic keyword of C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no such thing in the Java Programming Language; it is a strictly [statically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) language. There are, however, other programming languages that target the JVM, such as Groovy, that do indeed support dynamic typing.

Comment: Scala is a statically typed language, it only uses type inference to omit type declaration in most places. Groovy, Jython and JRuby are dynamic languages for the JVM.

Comment: C# is a statically typed language, too, and still it supports dynamic. So the reason is not about the "static" nature of the language. To support dynamic, you only need reflection and the actual work on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

No, not that I know of, but having said that, there are other languages supported by the JVM that do use dynamic typing, such as Jython and I believe Groovy, and so it *is* possible to have your cake and eat it too, just not the particular flavor of cake that you requested above.